# How do I only fill down when a column is 1 in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a signal column and I want to create a NewSignal column that only takes the value of Signal when Allowed column is 1, otherwise it should keep its own previous value:

```
df:
        Signal  Allowed  NewSignal
    0       -1        0          0
    1       -1        0          0
    2       -1        0          0
    3       -1        1         -1
    4       -1        1         -1
    5       -1        1         -1
    6       -1        1         -1
    7       -1        0         -1
    8       -1        0         -1
    9        1        0         -1
    10       1        1          1
    11       1        1          1
    12       1        1          1
```

When I try to create NewSignal like this:

```
df['NewSignal'] = 0
df['NewSignal'] = np.where(df['Allowed'] == 1,df['Signal'],df['NewSignal'].shift(1))
```

NewSignal is NOT correct on row 7:

```
    Signal  Allowed  NewSignal
0       -1        0        NaN
1       -1        0        0.0
2       -1        0        0.0
3       -1        1       -1.0
4       -1        1       -1.0
5       -1        1       -1.0
6       -1        1       -1.0
7       -1        0        0.0
8       -1        0        0.0
9        1        0        0.0
10       1        1        1.0
11       1        1        1.0
12       1        1        1.0
```

Comment: Could you post the original NewSignal?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I don't think there's an original `NewSignal`. OP wants to create a new column entirely.

Comment: @MayankPorwal For me the question is confusing. What "keep its own previous value" means then?

Comment: @DaniMesejo So what he means is, if `Allowed == 0`, then populate previous row value of `NewSignal`. In this case, ideally the first `3` rows should be `NaN` since `Allowed == 0`, then for rows `3 to 6`, `Allowed == 1`, so populate `Signal`'s value in `NewSignal`. Then for rows `7 to 9`, `Allowed == 0` so populate `NewSignal` value from row `6`. Similarly for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `ffill` with `where`

```
df['Nsg'] = df.Signal.where(df.Allowed==1).ffill()
Out[253]: 
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    -1.0
4    -1.0
5    -1.0
6    -1.0
7    -1.0
8    -1.0
9    -1.0
10    1.0
11    1.0
12    1.0
Name: Signal, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Anyway I can make initial nans 0 in same statement?

Comment: Use `df.Signal.where(df.Allowed==1).ffill().fillna(0)`.

Comment: @ManInMoon adding fillna(0) at the end

Comment: Man that's easy!